# What's the difference between a class and a style?

Tags: packages, document-classes

What are the actual differences between the two? I am new to LaTeX and I need to create a custom "look & feel" -- should I be looking into making a class or a style?

Comment: Are you really required to make a custom look and feel? There are many, many different ready-made solutions to choose from. If your customisations are really just a different typeface or margin requirements etc. it's better to choose a standard class and use a few packages and commands to tweak things.

Comment: I need some pretty specific details. I'm going to start looking for pre-made ones, but I would still like to know the difference between the two.

Comment: You should use an existing class and start a .sty file with your customization of it.  Pretty much everything can be customized starting with a class like `article`, or `book`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21909/classes-and-packages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question directly: imho, you should start by seeing if you can tweak one of the ready-made `documentclass`, and if you really can't get it to look the way you want  (which is really quite unlikely), then consider making your own (but I don't think anyone would recommend this until you've experimented extensively with the choices described below).

Some basic `documentclass` examples:

- `article` is one of the most simple, and will allow the highest section level as `section`
- `report` and `book` are the next ones up from `article` and will make the highest section level as `chapter`

In each of these classes, you will likely use *packages* to help you tweak the appearance such as

- `geometry` to get your page dimensions setup
- `fancyhdr` to get your headers and footers
- `enumitem` to customize your enumerations
- `titlesec` to customize your section/chapter headings

The `tufte-book` class has some particularly aesthetically pleasing settings by default.

Once you are familiar with these classes, you can move on to some of the more intricate classes such as `memoir`, `koma-script`, etc. I describe these as intricate because some of the packages that work with the 'basic' classes do *not* work with these (they have their own way of doing the same thing).

Once you've produced a few simple documents and you want to put some 'bling' into them, you could start by reading the following post, and the answers within:

[How to add some visual style and pizzazz to course notes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34301/how-to-add-some-visual-style-and-pizzazz-to-course-notes/34306#34306)

Answer (score 8):

In modern LaTeX a class is one of the major formats for documents. It is invoked using `\documentclass`. Style files sit on top of these, and are invoked using `\usepackage`. If you *absolutely have to* make something, then make an example document using a standard class first, then use some `newpackages`, `newcommands` and other tweaks to get it looking how you like, and then bundle those bits of your preamble into a style file. **Do not** start making a style file straight away. This will only lead to frustration.