# Defining a wrapper class for a set of document classes

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

Until now, I have been collecting my "frequently used packages", custom macros, and configurations in a personal style file. However, some of those configurations depend on the use of one of the `KOMA-Script` classes, and therefore (according to my own [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21910/510) to [Classes and packages – what's the difference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21909/classes-and-packages-whats-the-difference)) good practice stipulates that I rewrite my personal file into a wrapper class.

According to section A.4.8 of the *LaTeX Companion*, a wrapper class file `myclass.cls` that builds on `article.cls` and passes class options specified by the user to the base class would look like, e.g.,

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{<package list>}
```

or, even easier,

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\RequirePackage{<package list>}
```

However, my base class may in fact be one of several document classes, namely `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, or`scrbook`. I want to define some wrapper class options (named, say, `article`/`report`/`book`) that, by specifying one of them, load the corresponding `KOMA-Script` class. (If I don't specify any of them, `scrbook` shall be loaded by default.) How do I go on about this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This scheme seems to work:

```
\ProvidesClass{lockstep}
\DeclareOption{scrartcl}{\def\lock@class{scrartcl}}
\DeclareOption{scrreprt}{\def\lock@class{scrreprt}}
\DeclareOption{scrbook}{\def\lock@class{scrbook}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\lock@class}}
\ExecuteOptions{scrbook}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\lock@class}
```

The default class is **scrbook**, but the options `scrartcl` or `scrreprt` will change it.

In my test I tried with the `abstract` option:

```
\documentclass[abstract]{lockstep}
```

gives `Unused global option(s): [abstract]`, while

```
\documentclass[scrartcl,abstract]{lockstep}
```

doesn't show the message.

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me. I like the flexibility given by keys, but you have to `\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}` or to make your own format including it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
  \ProvidesClass{myclass}
  \RequirePackage{pgfopts}
  \pgfkeys{%
    /MyClassKeys/class/.store in = \MyClass,
    /MyClassKeys/class = scrbook}%
  \ProcessPgfOptions{/MyClassKeys}
  \LoadClassWithOptions{\MyClass}
\end{filecontents*}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\documentclass[class = extarticle,14pt]{myclass}

\begin{document}

This is my class using the \MyClass{} class

\end{document}
```

Note that is not actually a wrapper but the class itself. If find it easier to maintain (but a `.dtx` can also be a good solution to maintain different files, including some wrappers).

Comment: I'd rather avoid the need for a `\RequirePackage` in actual documents, but +1 for a solution using `pgfopts`.