# Using string conditionals to determine document class

Tags: conditionals

I am trying to set up a set of templates for most of the styles I have created or collected. Right now I am using a bunch of LaTeX files with the `\input{}` and setting variables with `\def`. What I am looking to accomplish is to have the template setup execute a series of steps depending on the variable sent. For example.

My main document will have something like this on the first couple of lines.

```
\def\doctype{letter} % this could also be a book, article, beamer presentation, etc.
\input{template-setup}
```

Based on the `doctype` I want to get my template setup to select the right document class. I know of the `xstring` or `xifthen` packages, but since I want to use the `doctype` variable to select the right document class, this is not possible (since you cannot use a package before `\documentclass`). Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) to mark them as code, as can be seen in my edit. (You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) or hit Ctrl + K.)

Comment: Why not just let `\doctype` be the document class itself? So then you can say `\documentclass{\doctype}`, and afterwards load the appropriate preamble.

Comment: You can use `\ifx`. See here for an example: [What does \ifx\\#1\\ stand for?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33823)

Comment: Thank you for the tip Torb. Peter, because I use the same documentclass for several styles and I also use that doctype variable to set the rest of the template. Marco Daniel, wow, what can I say? I am completely lost. Do you mean I can do something like this?
  
    `\ifx\doctype\letter 
        <code for #1 is empty>
    \else
        \ifx\doctype\book 
            <code for #1 is _not_ empty>
        \else
        \fi
    \fi`

Comment: Related: [Defining a wrapper class for a set of document classes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36274)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will use a general class file that can load the specific class as an option and create a boolean type test for all the different classes. The following is just a first try. It can be enhanced with keyvalues, etc.

*Edit 1:* Add command `\ClassList` to provide your own class list.

```
%%%% generalclass.cls %%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{generalclass}[2012/04/19 v0.1 General class (DNJ ELS)]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*\DeclareClassList[2]{%
    \def\@clsopt@select{#1}%-------------------- default class
    \edef\@clsopt@list{\zap@space#2 \@empty}%--- list of classes
    \@for\@clsopt@item:=\@clsopt@list\do{%
        \newbool{@clsopt@test@\@clsopt@item}%
        \csedef{@clsopt@def@\@clsopt@item}{%
            \def\noexpand\@clsopt@select{\@clsopt@item}}}
    \edef\@currclass@opt{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}%
    \@for\CurrentOption:=\@currclass@opt\do{%--- Go through documents options
        \ifcsdef{@clsopt@def@\CurrentOption}{%
            \csuse{@clsopt@def@\CurrentOption}%
            \csdef{ds@\CurrentOption}{}%
            \@use@ption}{}}}

\newcommand*\ThisClass{}
\newcommand\SetClassOption{%
    \edef\@clsopt@temp{%
        \noexpand\booltrue{@clsopt@test@\@clsopt@select}%
        \def\noexpand\ThisClass{\@clsopt@select}}%
    \@clsopt@temp}

\newcommand\IfClass[3]{%
    \ifbool{@clsopt@test@#1}{#2}{#3}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\providecommand*\ClassDefault{article}                   % Edit 1
\providecommand*\ClassList{article,report,book,letter}   % Edit 1
\DeclareClassList{\ClassDefault}{\ClassList}             % Edit 1 
\SetClassOption

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\ThisClass}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\ThisClass}
\endinput
```

---

It can then be used as follows:

```
\newcommand*\DocType{memoir}
\newcommand*\FontSize{10pt}
\newcommand*\PaperSize{a4paper}

%---- [ Put this in template for \input{} ] -------------
\newcommand*\ClassList{article,report,book,letter,memoir}
\documentclass[\DocType,\FontSize, \PaperSize]{generalclass}
%% Usage
%\IfClass{article}{..<true>..}{..<false..}
%\IfClass{report}{..<true>..}{..<false..}
%\IfClass{book}{..<true>..}{..<false..}
%\IfClass{letter}{..<true>..}{..<false..}
%\IfClass{memoir}{..<true>..}{..<false..}
%---- [ End template ] ----------------------------------

\begin{document}
    This class is: \ThisClass \par
    This is \IfClass{article}{an}{not an} article class document\par
    This is \IfClass{report}{a}{not a} report class document\par
    This is \IfClass{book}{a}{not a} book class document\par
    This is \IfClass{letter}{a}{not a} letter class document\par
    This is \IfClass{memoir}{a}{not a} memoir class document\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow Daniel, this is perfect. Thank you very much for providing the code. This is WAY beyond my knowledge of LaTex. I read and re-read until I figured out what was going on. If I had any reputation I would give you points for this answer.

I am know scratching my head thinking how to use something like memoir (so I can use the document class `article` and `memoir` and the `article` option. How would you go about accomplishing this? Should I create another question for that?

Comment: @tuxtlequino: I have changed the code a little bit to make it more general

Comment: Daniel, I spent hours trying to find documentation for some of the things that you used in the code you provided without any meaningful results. Could you please point me somewhere I can figure out your code, or even better, could you document every line explaining what is happening?

Comment: I think I did not made myself clear on my second question. The improvements to the code are appreciated but I still cannot do something like this...

`\documentclass{10pt,oneside,article}{memoir}` or this `\documentclass{10pt,oneside,book}{memoir}`

Comment: @tuxtlequino: Regarding the code, it is mostly for the source of the LaTeX kernel (see `source2e.pdf`) taken from the `\ProcessOptions` commands. For the second part the class type is now alway an optional argument for `generalclass` e.g. `\documentclass[<options>, article]{generalclass}` or `\documentclass[<options>, memoir]{generalclass}`. Please look at the example!

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I actually tested a couple things but failed to realize how important was the order of things. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How can we extend the `IfClass{...}{TRUE}{FALSE}` command to accept the argument with multiple classes such as `IfClass{article,book,memoir}{TRUE}{FALSE}` for example.

Comment: @ADP: That will be very difficult

Answer (score 1):

You can define macros which hold the different values (`letter`, `book`, etc.) and then compare it with `\doctype` using `\ifx\firstmacro\secondmacro <equal> \else <not equal> \fi`:

```
\def\doctype{letter} % this could also be a book, article, beamer presentation, etc.
% ..
\def\doctypeletter{letter}
\def\doctypebook{book}
% ...

\ifx\doctype\doctypeletter
  % doctype is 'letter'
\else
\ifx\doctype\doctypebook
  % doctype is 'book'
\fi
\fi
```

---

Note that it is also possible (but not always recommendable) to load a package before the class using `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`.

---

You could also make your own class files which load the real class using `\LoadClassWithOptions{<real class>}` and then include your required settings for this class.

Comment: Arg, just seeing now that tuxtlequino posted basically the same as comment 11 hours ago! Well I keep it for now.