# .cls vs .sty files

Tags: packages, document-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Classes and packages – what's the difference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21909/classes-and-packages-whats-the-difference)

Here is a simple question with a little background.  My company just started using LaTeX for our documents, and there has been some debate/confusion as to the difference between a `.cls` file and a `.sty` file, since it appears that global commands will when placed in either file.

Currently, we use the `.cls` file for all the `\gdef`'s and `\newcommand`'s and things of that nature; while the `.sty` file is used for all things relating to the document as a whole such as the `\usepackage` commands and defining colors, etc.

Is this the way they were intended or are we missing something?