# Missing \begin{document}. error in TexWorks

Tags: errors, document-classes

Below is the LaTeX code for which I am getting the LaTeX error "missing `\begin {document}`. How can I resolve this error?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{MY CV}

\begin{document}
    Hello!
\end{document}
```

And this is the error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Do not create your own class file with spaces in them. That is, instead of `MY CV.cls`, create `MYCV.cls` and use

```
\documentclass[..]{MYCV}
```

Comment: I haven't created any class file. That's why I'm getting another error .cls not found.

Comment: @MehulBhatt: You don't have to *create* a class file for every document you want to create. There are a number of default classes available (`article`, `book` and `report`, for example) and some people have written classes for specific purposes. If you're interested in creating a CV, consider using something like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). Perhaps you can start with [an online template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262576/5764) *first*. Also of interest would be reading [Classes and packages – what's the difference?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21909/5764)

Answer (score 0):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{MY CV}
```

This is not ment to specify your file "MY CV". 
Instead it should contain something like:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

to specify, what type of document you are writing.

Have closer look at some tutorials/instructions :)

Edit:
You can actually specify a class like "MY CV" (or "MYCV"), but this does not seem to be the issue...

Edit2:
As mentioned by Werner, the "MY CV"-part IS the issue. Changing it to "MYCV" will solve this, if a "MYCV.cls" exists.

Comment: What does `\documentclass{article article} \begin{document} test \end{document}` yield when you compile it?

Comment: I get the same error-message, as shown in the question above.
But I have not tried to write a class file, with a name separated by spaces.

Comment: So why would you say "this does not seem to be the issue..." if a space introduced in the name of a document class replicates the error (even if the class does not exist)?

Comment: The class name "MY CV" looked somewhat like a beginners try on a first latex-document, so i assumed, he needed a more general help.

Maybe I should not read that much between the lines, but I still have to learn many things on forums, as I am very new too.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes this was my first attempt at LaTeX and as a matter of fact I didnt know that I also have to create a class file